# ContextMenuStrip selected item lost in UserControl

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, user-controls, contextmenu

I have a VB.NET User Control which is embedded into another User Control and that into a form.  The inner User Control has a contextmenustrip triggered by a DataGridView row click.  This successfully activates the event handler (I see the "OK" message), but the sender does not send the selected item (I don't see the other MsgBox messages).  Here is the code:

```
Public CMSV As ContextMenuStrip

Private grdSourceViewerCurrentRow As Long

Public Sub grdSourceViewer_RowHeaderMouseClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles grdSourceViewer.RowHeaderMouseClick
    'code to review/edit source details
     Select Case e.Button
        Case Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right
            grdSourceViewerCurrentRow = e.RowIndex  'retain for downstream code
            CMSV = New ContextMenuStrip
            AddHandler CMSV.MouseClick, AddressOf SourceViewDocumentationEdit
            CMSV.Items.Add("Edit")
            CMSV.Items.Add("Transfer to Evidence")
            Dim Pt As Point = New Point()
            Pt.X = grdSourceViewer.PointToClient(Cursor.Position).X
            Pt.Y = grdSourceViewer.PointToClient(Cursor.Position).Y + 20

            CMSV.Show(sender, Pt)

        Case Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left
            Exit Sub
        Case Else
            Exit Sub
    End Select
End Sub

Public Sub SourceViewDocumentationEdit()
    MsgBox("OK") 'I can see it reaches here
    Dim cc As ToolStripItemCollection = CMSV.Items
    Dim SelectedItem As Integer = -1
    Dim SelectedValue As String = ""

    For i As Integer = 0 To cc.Count - 1
        If cc.Item(i).Selected Then
            SelectedItem = i
            SelectedValue = cc.Item(SelectedItem).Text
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    Select Case SelectedValue
        Case "Edit"
            MsgBox("Edit code here")
        Case "Transfer to Evidence"
            MsgBox("Transfer code here")
    End Select
End Sub
```

What is wrong here?  Why am I losing the info about the item that was clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you recreating the menu each time?

At any rate, store the ToolStripMenuItem returned by CMSV.Items.Add() and wire that up instead.

Simplified example:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    CMSV = New ContextMenuStrip
    Dim TSMI As ToolStripMenuItem
    TSMI = CMSV.Items.Add("Edit")
    AddHandler TSMI.Click, AddressOf TSMI_Click
    TSMI = CMSV.Items.Add("Transfer to Evidence")
    AddHandler TSMI.Click, AddressOf TSMI_Click
    ' ...
End Sub

Private Sub TSMI_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim TSMI As ToolStripMenuItem = DirectCast(sender, toolstripmenuitem)
    Select Case TSMI.Text
        Case "Edit"
            Debug.Print("...Edit Code...")
            ' use "grdSourceViewerCurrentRow " in here?
        Case "Transfer to Evidence"
            Debug.Print("...Transfer to Evidence Code...")
            ' use "grdSourceViewerCurrentRow " in here?
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Both of you are correct and helpful.  I needed to set up the CM once and set up an event handler for both CM items.  This works.  My strategy was working in user controls which were not nested, but this complexity revealed my flawed logic.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `ToolStripMenuItem` and not just a string. Then you can add the handler for it's click event.

```
Dim tsmi As New ToolStripMenuItem
tsmi.Text = "Edit"
AddHandler tsmi.Click, AddressOf ItemClicked
CMSV.Items.Add(tsmi)
```

Then the event sub:

```
Private Sub ItemClicked(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
 'item clicked
 'sender object would be the ToolStripMenuItem
End Sub
```

Comment: This does not work for me; I tried it.  CMSV.Items.Add can accept either a text string or a ToolStripMenuItem.  In either case, it creates the item.  So there is something more complex causing this problem.